Differences between “in average” and “on average”?
Let me start with a sentence that I’ve written:

____ average, students in the class performed well on that exam.

It was confusing, which should I choose “in” or “on” for the option given to fill in the blank?
I have searched for some resources, and each gives me different explanations, which make me confused.
Explanation 1: Quora
See here.
The explanation given is as below:

It depends what follows. If it’s something that happens many times during the day, “in” usually better. If it’s something that happens once, “on” is better.
Good: On an average day, one just like today, Jeff and Lisa got married.
Bad: In an average day, one just like today, Jeff and Lisa got married.
Good: In an average day, you touch your face 3,800 times.
Bad: On an average day, you touch your face 3,800 times.

Explanation 2: italki
Link: https://www.italki.com/en/post/7EVzbPSgqqwNtEL50Nj41H#
One of those answers wrote:

On average means that something is generally at about that level.
‘in’ goes with ‘increase’. There has been an increase in the price of food.

Explanation 3: Reddit
Link: https://www.reddit.com/r/ENGLISH/comments/13ahtmr/is_it_on_an_average_or_at_an_average/

“On average” is the more common phrase.

Explanation 4: TwoMinEnglish
Link: https://twominenglish.com/in-average-or-on-average/

English learners wonder if they should say “in average” or “on average.” The correct phrase is “on average.” This phrase is used when talking about a normal amount, based on adding together several numbers and dividing by the count of these numbers.
“In average” is a relic of the past, whereas “on average” is the universally recognized form for conveying average values or general numbers in the English language.”


Many of these resources say that “in average” isn’t a common phrase, the native speakers used “ on average. (Explanation 3 and 4)
But Explanation 1 and 2 didn’t mention that, and these two sites have different explanations, so I’m very confused.
Question: Which of these explanation(s) are correct?

The word is explanation. No. 4 is correct. Quora is right in saying that in an average day is correct, but that's a different kind of sentence.

@KateBunting Typo errors, I have fixed the issue.

"If it’s something that happens many times during the day, “in” is usually better. If it’s something that happens once, “on” is better." I hate that explanation from Quora in the first link. I suspect that we have mini Venn Diagrams in our head to work out which is most appropriate in general conversation. Nice question; I'd never considered this

In the "Explanation 1: Quora" example, the second one marked as bad is... not bad?  "On an average day you do this 20 times" is completely acceptable and normal to say. Oddly enough, it no longer works if you use a longer time period, though. "In an average year..." is fine, "On an average year" sounds weird. Anyway. Explanation 2 seems completely incoherent to me, maybe I'm missing something.

I should say -- that isn't unique to this particular usage and has nothing to do with referring to averages; it's days and other time periods that have different usage. "On a day" is normal, but "on a month" doesn't work. You'd need to say "In a month" or "In a year". (For that matter, you can do something in a minute but not on a minute.)

"in average" is just two words that wouldn't normally appear consecutively, but "on average" is a two-word adverb that works just like, say, usually (which it often means much the same as).

A- "I have four explanations,  I don't know which one is right".   B -"Let me help you.....".  A- "Now I have five explanations."

@JamesK So what are you trying to say?

Nothing  much.  (2) (3) and (4) all say the same.  The correct phrase is "on average".   (1) is talk about something else.  (1) is not about whether "In average" or "on average" is right, it is about "in/on an average X".    So I don't see the problem.

'Average' can be a noun and an adjective.

In the phrase "on average", it is a noun. We say "on" because that preposition can indicate a reference or basis for making a statement, similar to how we use "on" in phrases like "on the whole" or "on balance". It is wrong to say "in average" when using 'average' as a noun.

In a phrase like "in an average day", 'average' is an adjective describing the noun "day". "In" is idiomatic because we can talk about something happening in a day when we mean that something happens within 24 hours, although it is also fine to say "on an (average) day" when we are referring to the day or date as a whole.



@Ihatmaths Note, it's also pretty easy to find examples of "in average," as long as "average" is still an adjective, like "in average people." It's a valid usage to use "average" to modify plurals, but it's actually more common to use a singular like "in the average person," as if one imaginary person stands for a large group. When we use "average" to modify a group it might give it more of a meaning about quality, like "no better than ordinary," instead of its neutral meaning of "typical."

@AndyBonner Yep, that's why I said it's wrong when using average as a noun.

I would say 'in average' where the average referred to the conditions, or the populuation being measured and there is some additional description around the fact, where I would say on average where I was referring more directly to the result.
eg
in average classes (of around 30 people) there will be two people sharing a birthday.
in average conditions it takes 9 1/2 hours to drive to London.
but
on average it rains 10 days a month
on average it takes 9 1/2 hours to get to London.
